# Jquery-ui Sortable with different height working, but with positioning error. Any solution to this?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, css-float, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a working jquery-ui sortable already that can handle different heights and width, but the problem comes when it is positioned like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/N52GP/7/

What it should look like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OydUg.jpg

I know this is a CSS floating problem, and I can't find any solution to it been testing and searching for hours now. Even if I set the Box 4 to float: right it would still show on the same height as Box 3.

See code in HTML / CSS floating problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <style>
        .portlet {
            float: left;
            margin: 5px;
            background-color: #b5b5b5;
        }

        #box1, #box4 {
            width: 150px;
            height: 220px;
        }

        #box2, #box3 {
            width: 250px;
            height: 100px;
        }
    </style>

    <div style="float: left; width: 600px; padding: 10px;">

        <div id="box1" class="portlet">
            <div class="portlet-header">Box 1</div>
            <div class="portlet-content">Box Desc</div>
        </div>

        <div id="box2" class="portlet">
            <div class="portlet-header">Box 2</div>
            <div class="portlet-content">Box Desc</div>
        </div>

        <div id="box3" class="portlet">
            <div class="portlet-header">Box 3</div>
            <div class="portlet-content">Box Desc</div>
        </div>

        <div id="box4" class="portlet">
            <div class="portlet-header">Box 4</div>
            <div class="portlet-content">Box Desc</div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

The div boxes don't fit side-by-side in the `#sortable` container.

You need to expand the container and if you really must use floats, you need to wrap `#box2` and `#box3` in a `div` as well

Try:

```
<div id="middle">
    <div id="box2" class="portlet">
        <div class="portlet-header">Box 2</div>
        <div class="portlet-content">Box Desc</div>
    </div>

    <div id="box3" class="portlet">
        <div class="portlet-header">Box 3</div>
        <div class="portlet-content">Box Desc</div>
    </div>
</div>


#middle {
    float:left; 
    width:258px;
}
```

Comment: All four boxes fit the #sortable container, otherwise box 4 would be on the next line below the three boxes. Is there a way to put #box2 and #box3 inside a div using jquery-ui sortable? What if it was arrange as #box4, #box1, #box3, then #box2 at first and the user wanted to arrange it to the way it is now? Is there a way to put #box2 and #box3 inside a floated div if it is arranged that way using jquery?

Comment: What I meant was the combination of `#box1` + `#box2` + `#box3` don't fit side by side.  Therefore #box3 gets floated onto the next line. Then `#box4` continues on, aligned with `#box3`.

Comment: Yes that is intended that #box2 and #box3 are on the same column just like what I showed in this image in my original post this should be the correct output if a user arranged the sortable boxes like this: http://i.imgur.com/NkDxn.jpg

Comment: The HTML code you added would work if the position of the boxes are fixed, but how could you make jquery-ui sortable boxes add that for that movable boxes? See the working sortable boxes I already made here: http://jsfiddle.net/N52GP/7/ - as you can see the boxes position are dynamic and is based on the users selection.